# Dependencies of python2, e. g. GIMP

Tags: python-2.7

After installing in 18.04 (upgraded from 16.04) python3 I removed python2 by

```
sudo apt autoremove python2
sudo apt autoremove python2.7
```

As I now realized this was stupid.
But I don't understand why GIMP doesn't work any more now.
Is it enough to install GIMP again?
And should I install python2 again?

Comment: which Ubuntu version?

Comment: @pLumo 18.04 (upgraded vom 16.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many components of Ubuntu 18.04 may depend on Python 2.7. Never remove the default python in Ubuntu.

First install python2 with

```
sudo apt install python
```

If GIMP still does not work, you can reinstall it with

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gimp
```